Procedural sound synthesis: "primal" / animalistic / human-but-NOT-speech grunts / screams / groans / moans etc
I've embarked on this gamedev idea situated in a procedurally-generated stone-age / primeval pre-language / pre-civilizational world, with all sorts of critters & beasts, flora & fauna, but also humanesque / humanoid species. Not exact replica of earth but relatable-enough (roughly like many procedural-planet plays aim for / achieve).
For immersion and non-repetetiveness I want the soundscape to be procedurally synthesized as well, and apart from weather sounds (not the topic here) it'll be full of the whole range of animalistic / primal voicings really, whether coming from the various animal kingdoms (mammals, birds, reptiles, insects) or the humanoids in their hunts, fights, sports, play. In the end, we're talking screams, groans, grunts, moans, bird chirps, humanoid giggles, etc.
Are there algorithmic research works or fields (or blogs / code explorations) that have dealt with this particular sujet? (I imagine this constraining by non-speech allows voice & onomatopoeia techniques and explorations that would be out of order if speech was required.) I know there's procedural-sound work for engine / machinery stuff (unneeded here), wind / weather (will deal with that separately) etc. And then there's TTS and generative music both of which is decidedly entirely not-needed here. But about this whole "primal voicings" direction? Any prior work I should catch up on and study, that anyone knows of?

This looks like a better question to ask on the Sound Design StackExchange, because what you need is input from experts in audio synthesis. The fact that you'll later use that audio in a game is secondary. Once you have your synthesis routines, we can help you here if you need support integrating them into your game (say, finding ways to optimize performance so the audio synthesis fits in your frame/memory budgets). But we don't necessarily have the right audio experts here to tell you how to approach generating these sounds in the first place.

Two tips to help you get better answers: 1) StackExchange questions should invite a custom-written answer. Questions that can be answered with links to existing documents like papers are usually better to ask a search engine. So ask for solutions, not references.
We expect you to have done that research before asking. 2) Ask about one problem/topic at a time. Mammal/bird/insect sounds will likely all demand very different techniques. Pick one to start with and ask about that 1st, then you can build on it.
